# Is $(x^2+y^2-1,z-iy)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Is $(x^2+y^2-1,z-iy)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$? How can I prove it?

I need this to decompose the algebraic set $V(x^2+y^2-1,x^2-z^2-1)$ into irreductible components.

Comment: How is your question related to your last statement about the variety? They look like fundamentally different expressions.

Comment: you can show that $V(x^2+y^2-1,x^2-z^2-1) = V(x^2+y^2-1,z-iy) \cup V(x^2+y^2-1,z+iy)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. We have $$\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(X^2+Y^2-1,Z-iY)\simeq\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$$ and then need to prove that $X^2+Y^2-1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb C[X,Y]$. Can you do this by yourself?

Comment: irreducible implies prime in $\mathbb C[x,y]$? im a little confused because $f=y^2+x^2(x+1)^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R [x,y]$ but the algebraic set $V(f)$ is reducible i.e. $I(V(f))$ isn't prime

Comment: @Maximiliano Maybe we are talking about different things: a polynomial $f$ is irreducible iff $(f)$ (the ideal generated by $f$) is a prime ideal, and this is what you want to show, right?

Comment: Yes, diferent things, but in $\mathbb C = \bar {\mathbb C}$ i only need to show that $(x^2+y^2-1)$ is prime (because the Hibert's nullstellensatz need a closed field) to prove what i want. Thanks for thr help ;)